# Search for two-letter words in Lucene

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I'm trying to find documents containing the acronym "IT".

I've tried searching using the StandardAnalyzer, SimpleAnalyzer and KeywordAnalyzer - same result (no hits whatsoever).

As far as I can see, "it" isn't part of the default stop words?

I *can* find the documents using a wildcard search, so I know they're in the index.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default stopword set does include the word "it".  It is defined in `StopAnalyzer`, and it is:

```
final List<String> stopWords = Arrays.asList(
   "a", "an", "and", "are", "as", "at", "be", "but", "by",
   "for", "if", "in", "into", "is", "it",
   "no", "not", "of", "on", "or", "such",
   "that", "the", "their", "then", "there", "these",
   "they", "this", "to", "was", "will", "with"
 );
```

Neither `SimpleAnalyzer` nor `KeywordAnalyzer` use stopwords, so these didn't work due to some other issue, possibly a misunderstanding of how they tokenize, or a disagreement between index and query time analyzers.

Comment: Weird, I didn't see "it" among the stop words in Lucene 3.0. Probably just missed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I tried re-indexing without *any* stop words...

```
new IndexWriter(directory,
                new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_30, new HashSet<string>()), // No stop words
                true,
                IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);
```

...and after that I was able to search for "**it**" as long as I used the same type of analyzer (without any stop words) for searching:

```
new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_30, new HashSet<string>()
```