# How to index state abbreviations with the lucene standard analyzer?

Tags: lucene.net

I'm having trouble with indexing state abbreviation codes such as  IN, OR with lucene .net.  If I use the standard analyzer when Indexing, I cannot retreive documents by these state abbreviations.  If I use the simple analyzer when indexing, I can retreive documents based on these abbreviations, but other queries such as zipcodes indexed as strings no longer work.

Any suggestions on what the best practice for this type of lucene dilemna would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Search for two-letter words in Lucene](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18255015/search-for-two-letter-words-in-lucene)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I4V, that post was the same issue.  I resolved it by changing my code from

This was a duplicate question.  After reading the post

```
_standardAnalyzer = new Lucene.Net.Analysis.Standard.StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30
```

To:

This was a duplicate question.  After reading the post

```
_standardAnalyzer = new Lucene.Net.Analysis.Standard.StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30, new HashSet<string>());
```